# file size calculated via FilterInputStream is 12.5% higher than actual

Tags: java, inputstream, java-io

I'm trying to limit the file size uploaded to my application via below class. 
I'm reading the inputstream and throwing exception when file size exceeds the limit.

But surprising thing is that number of bytes read by below code is always 12.5% greater than actual file size. I've tried it for multiple files.

Tried googling it but couldn't find any satisfactory response.

Is there any specific reason for this? If yes then how to correct it?

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.exceptions.SomeErrorCode;
import com.exceptions.SomeFileSizeException;
import com.logger.MyLogger;

/**
 * InputStream that guards the maxim number of bytes to allow to be read. It throws an IOException if the size is exceeded.
 */
public class SizeLimitedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

  private long maxSize = 0;
  private long currentSize = 0;

  public SizeLimitedInputStream(InputStream in, long maxSize) {
    super(in);
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
  }

  private void checkLimit(long size) throws SomeFileSizeException {
    currentSize += size;
    if (currentSize > maxSize) {
      throw new SomeFileSizeException(SomeErrorCode.FILE_SIZE_TOO_LONG, "File Size cannot exceed " + maxSize + " bytes.");
    }
  }

  public long getMaxSize() {
    return maxSize;
  }

  @Override
  public int read() throws IOException, SomeFileSizeException {
    checkLimit(1);
    return super.read();
  }

  @Override
  public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException, SomeFileSizeException {
    return super.read(b);
  }

  @Override
  public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException, SomeFileSizeException {
    checkLimit(len);
    return super.read(b, off, len);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why does one of the read methods ignore the limit?

Comment: @Kayaman because the read(byte[] b) method simply calls read(byte[] b, int off, int len) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ignoring the return value of `read()` which tells the **actual** number of bytes read and using `len` instead.

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem but I can't understand why there was always an increase of 12.5% read bytes for all files. Does it have something to do with buffer read.

Comment: Possibly a buffer 1/8 bigger than a native buffer / packet size.